# Unable to import sql.connector in VScode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, mysql-connector-python, modulenotfounderror

```
import mysql.connector

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost', user='root',passwd='password', auth_plugin='mysql_native_password')
```

I am doing same thing in Jupyter notebook, it is working there but in VScode it shows:
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysql'`
All other package I install work fine but having trouble only with this.
I have installed using pip. Any solution for this?
Of course I could work with Jupyter notebook but I like vscode more so ....
`Python 3.8.3`
`pip 20.2.3`
Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced the same error when I'm using Pycharm. Installing other packages works for me. You could try and install this and try running if it solves your problem.

```
pip install mysql-connector-python-rf
```

Another solution would be restarting your local IDE which is VScode. I used VScode as my main IDE and installing some modules in python makes it raised an error like `ModuleNotFound`. Restarting it solved the problem.

Comment: Yes absolutely worked! Can I get some resource to read more about it?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/ I think this is just another name for  it. But you can always check out their website for further information.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue as you. What I did was press <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd>. Will pop up to select Python interpreter. Go and select the interpreter of python that is in your virtual environment. The one that is in your scripts. Mine was fine after I did that.